# In Miruken can I return a promise from the initialize method of a Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a TeamController with an initialize function that initializes the team property.

```
new function() {
  mlm.package(this, {
    name:    "team",
    imports: "miruken.mvc",
    exports: "TeamController"
  });
  eval(this.imports);
  const TeamController = Controller.extend({
    $properties:{
      teams: []
    },
    initialize() {
      this.base();
      TeamFeature(this.context).getTeams().then(teams => {
         this.teams = teams;
      });      
    }
  });
  eval(this.exports);
};
```

If I return the promise from the initialize function my controller is not available in the view to be bound.

```
return TeamFeature(this.context).getTeams().then(teams => {
    this.teams = teams;
});
```

I thought I could return a promise from the initialize function to force the loading to wait until the promise was resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miruken uses an IOC container that fully supports promises.  When a component is resolved from the container, if it has an initialize function the initialize function will be called. If the initialize function returns a promise, then a promise is returned from the container that resolves to the requested component.

Unfortunately, Angular and the UI-Router do not support asynchronous component resolution.  So, the UI is actually trying to bind to a promise and not the 
resolved controller.  To make your code work you have 2 options.

1. Don't return a promise from the initialize function when using the UI-Router.
2. Use miruken's region directive, and the ViewRegion protocol to compose your view.  Regions respect promises, and will wait to load the view until promises returned from initialize are resolved.